# Что ищет это выражение?

Tags: математика, mathematica

n! / (k! * (n - k)!) - это значение функции math.comb(n, k)

Comment: Это для спортлото. 6 из 49.

Answer (score 4):

Количество [сочетаний](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) `k` элементов без повторений из общего количества `n` элементов.

Answer (score 2):

Это формула математики раздела комбинаторики. 
Эта формула ищет сочетание элементов `к`из общего `n` кол-ва элементов.